# How do I display content of a post to a page on click, wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hi this is what I'm trying to do. I have a page, and on that page is a div with a list of posts in it and when I click one of those posts, I would like to display the content of that post, in a seperate div, on the same page. and when I click on another post, the content of the post replaces the first content and so on. 
is this possible? and how would I acheive this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: See how to ask first(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can show post content into a specific div element when a link is clicked, without having to refresh the page or going to an inner page.

You can set `<div id="single-post-container"></div>` div something like this and on click you can append post content inside this element using ajax method.

Please follow [this](https://stanhub.com/load-wordpress-post-content-with-ajax-and-jquery/) tutorial. They have explained the same method as you want on your site.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Had a little trouble getting jquery to work properly in wordpress but this is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using bootsrap modal via attribute. Check this link out where I demo it

https://www.codeply.com/go/gIcBhBLhxW